# Django - how to pass a value from <a href> to a view

Tags: python, django

I have a category dropdown list in a template. I don't want to hard code it and write separate list views for each category. So is there a way to pass a value from `<a href="">` to a view? I guess `self.request.GET.get('category search')` never works because there is no `<form method="get">` tag. Therefor it always returns `None` due to the `return queryset.none()` statement.

**home.html:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    {% if all_categories %}
        {% for category in all_categories %}
            <a name="category search" href="{% url 'book:category_search' category.id %}"> {{ category }} </a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**book.urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    .........
    path('categories/<int:pk>', views.CategorySearchView.as_view(), name='category_search'),
]
```

**book.views.py:**

```
class CategorySearchView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'book/search.html'
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        search = self.request.GET.get('category search')
        if search:
            queryset = Book.objects.filter(categories__id=search)
            return queryset
        else:
            return queryset.none()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your URL has `<int:pk>`,

```
path('categories/<int:pk>', views.CategorySearchView.as_view(), name='category_search'),
```

you can access `self.kwargs['pk']` in the view:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    search = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    if search:
        queryset = Book.objects.filter(categories__id=search)
        return queryset
    else:
        return queryset.none()
```

As an aside, you would use `self.request.GET` if `pk` was in the querystring, e.g. `/categories/?pk=1`. When you submit a form with `method=GET`, the form fields will be included in the querystring. But you can also have a link with a querystring, e.g. `<a href="/categories/?pk=1">my link</a>`.

Comment: You can also do `<a href="{% url 'category_search' %}?pk={{ category_id }}">` if you removed `<int:pk>` from the `path()`. However, I would probably stick with `categories/<int:pk>` since it looks cleaner.